# System.Drawing namespace missing in aspnetVnext core CLR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

System.drawing namespace is not available in the coreCLR . I want to resize the image in the server and return store it.

To give more context my application uses markdown for content edition . once the image is uploaded I want to resize and apply it in HTML . I am making an assembly to work with coreclr not on the desktop .

Comment: It's *never* been [officially supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for use in asp.net. However, I don't think the recommended alternative (Windows Imaging Components) are available in Core CLR either.

Comment: You could add the reference to core and use it.

You can find it in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework`

Comment: I'm making great progress on a .NET Core imaging library that might be appropriate https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short answer (and only answer, for now) is yes, you're totally correct. System.Drawing isn't and will never be a good option for Core, especially since it's cross platform. We are looking at other solutions like a managed libgd wrapper as discussed here https://github.com/imazen/Graphics-vNext

Comment: Looks really interesting defiantly something like this is needed.  Looks like Imazen decided to not do the libgd.net port themselves per the update they posted today.

Comment: How it's going now? As far as I know System.Drawing was added to the next release of the .NET Core or ASP.NET core, is it correct?

Comment: @szhuravel No, just some primitives, Point, Rectangle etc to aid with interop.

Answer (score 1):

Alexander Köplinger started porting Mono's implementation of System.Drawing (and WinForms) to .NET Core. You can find his code at [github.com/akoeplinger/mono-winforms-netcore](https://github.com/akoeplinger/mono-winforms-netcore).

As fair warning though, he did say this about it:

> Mono's WinForms implementation didn't get much love in the recent years, so not sure if it has much use outside of experimental/hobby-stuff apps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows you could try Magick.Net (which wraps ImageMagick)
https://magick.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

A great and easy way to do picture conversion and manipulation is to use [Magick.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Magick.NET.Core-Q8/) (sample code for illustration):

```
using( MagickImage ThisPicture = new MagickImage( JpegPicture ) )
{
    ThisPicture.Scale( XDimensions, YDimensions );
    ThisPicture.ColorType = ColorType.Grayscale;
    ThisPicture.Extent( XDimensions, YDimensions, Gravity.Center, MagickColors.Black );

    using( PixelCollection ThisPixels = ThisPicture.GetPixels() )
    {
        byte Intensity = ThisPixels[ IX, IY ].GetChannel( 0 );
    }
}
```